# Why does my propane oven emit a chemical smell when in use?

Tags: stove, propane

We have a propane cook stove. Have been using it for several years.  Lately we are getting a very strong unpleasant odor when using the oven. Difficult to compare the smell to anything, but not pleasant. It is not the usual propane smell,much sharper and more 'chemically'. Seems to happen just when the oven comes back on, but not every time.  I haven't done any painting or anything for several years. I have moved the stove out and checked in the cupboards around it, and nothing there has changed. It only happens a coupe of times each time the oven is used, Never have this smell when using the stove-top burners.
When the oven is turned on initially, it takes up to 5 minutes for it to light, so the igniter is probably weak, but can't see how that would cause the problem, as it doesn't create that smell on initial start-up.

Comment: if it never happens two days in a row, my guess is that there's a build up of residue (grease, dust, etc) on some of the surfaces that get hot, like turning on the heat for the first time...

Comment: Inappropriate (and obsolete) comments have been deleted. Please keep the discussion civil and constructive.

Comment: LPG is required to be odorized with mercaptan like natural gas so that a leak will be noticed ; otherwise LPG and nat gas are odorless. I forget the amount of mercaptan but it is around a couple parts per million. So you have a leak.or improper combustion , or burning residue on the burner. The mercaptan burns to sulfur dioxide but there is so little the smell may not be noticed.

Answer (score 4):

Pull the oven burner and check for lint or any thing that could partially block the air inlet at the burner venturi. If you can see the flame, It should be blue and have a definite pattern not yellow and lazy. My last home had propane for cooking and the stove required more than normal maintenance. If the odor is a "burn your nose or eyes" kind of odor that usually means not enough combustion air at the flame, and a weird smell is what you get. – d.george 6 hours ago

Comment: I agree spiders love to put webs across the openings and build nests in the pipes, also check the holes on top haven't gotten rusty I see this on furnace burners all the time and use a wire brush to descale them.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for the last 6 months to a year. I seen others suggest it was an air flow issue. When I opened the oven I immediately noticed that my wife had placed a liner on the bottom of the oven. When I removed the liner I noticed this liner covered the 2 very large vent holes in the bottom of the oven. The smell changed/went away almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of a kerosene odor in the house is the presence of petroleum products like paint or oil. When drying paint mixes with traces of natural gas in the air (from your stove, water boiler, etc.), it produces an odor similar to kerosene. It's not dangerous - just thoroughly air out your house. This was useful information to me. I had just painted a sign with oil based paint and it was drying on the kitchen table. I removed the sign and the smell went away.

Comment: [What could cause kerosene-like odor from a gas oven/range?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16553/what-could-cause-kerosene-like-odor-from-a-gas-oven-range?rq=1), +1

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.