# Odor Coming From Oven

Tags: oven, smell, kerosene

I have a GE oven and am getting a strong odor when I use any of the burners or the oven. The odor reminds me of the smell a kerosene heater would put out when being used. I haven't cleaned the oven at all lately, and there hasn't been any kind of work done in my house. The smell is definitely coming from use of the oven.

Comment: See if something in this question helps.  Should mention type and age of oven in question.  The information you give, better answers can be given to your situation.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16553/what-could-cause-kerosene-like-odor-from-a-gas-oven-range?rq=1

Comment: Is it a gas or electric range? Make/model?

Comment: I'm not sure how old the oven is. It was here when I purchased my house and that was over 5 years ago. So I guess it's at least that old.. but it doesn't look much older than that. Also the oven is a GE with natural gas. I could also describe the odor as a lighter fluid like smell. My gas company come out and he said its emitting carbon monoxide but had no other insight for me other than that

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with gas, but it sounds like incomplete combustion for some reason, are the flames nice and blue or yellowish? Also, you might have a leak, if so, it would have a "rotten egg" smell. Be careful here, you have multiple hazards....wish I could be of more help. Be sure to read the link @crip659 provided, it may be your problem.

Comment: Flames are blue and everything seems normal. But the smell is very potent. Thanks for your input. I'll see if I can find something on that

Comment: Kind of surprised that gas company guy would say it is emitting CO and walk away.  Would think they disable it and tell you to get it fixed, at least.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't happen if you don't use the oven?

Comment: They only care if the problem is on their end. Since it's the appliance.. they couldn't care less. He advised me to open a window if I use it.. that's about all the help I got from him

Comment: Yes. There is no smell when the oven isn't in use. But anyone anywhere in the house would know if the oven was being used. That's how bad it is. I can't find anything on the internet about what the problem actually is. I find people experiencing the same problem.. but not how it was resolved. And the soonest I can get anyone out to look at it is 2 weeks

Comment: Type of building would also be useful, possible if close neighbours painted or spilled something?

Comment: Is the oven new?

Comment: The burners may need to be cleaned a wire brush will usually clean them it is that or not enough fresh air.

Comment: The source of the odor has been resolved. I live in a row home and found out they were redoing the floors next door (I had no idea). So it turns out whatever they were using.. I guess the stain or sealer was causing the fumes (which I or anyone else didn't even smell) were being burned off by the open flame creating the smell. I opened the windows for the day and now everything is back to normal. Thanks everyone for your help